# Error in my method for putting double time " "- XPATH with a specific Text

Tags: java, eclipse, xpath, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am trying to put this xpath in eclipse, but it does not work. Any idea?
I have to say that I put " " between HER'S SISTEM S.A because that name also has " ' " so I must use the " " to specify the specific text and my bot recognize this text , if I put 'Her's SISTEM S.A.' betweeen " ' " appears and error because there are triple " ' " . So I am not sure how to fix this in eclipse.

There is a text and inside another text on my method and I cannot use ' ' this because I have to use it with my xpath.

The method of my xpath is here:

WebElement SeleccionCuentaDeOportunidad =findBy(String.format("(//*[contains(@title,'Jonathan')]//parent::span[1]/parent::th[1]//following-sibling::td[position()=1]//child::a[1])[@title="HER'S SISTEM S.A."]"));

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's going to be hard to debug an xPath without a copy of the page's HTML or a link to the page in question--can you add either of those?  That said, `findBy(String.format` will not work to evaluate an xpath via selenium.  You can use

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("validXpath"))`

if you want to find an element by xpath.

Finally, if you want your code to be more readable, put four spaces at the beginning of the code line and `it will look pretty like this.`

Comment: @C.Peck thanks for your answer. But it's not a problem with the xpath, the problem is cause I use " " to selec the text "HER'S SISTEM S.A" , I can't select al the xpath with " " because it cause conflicts in eclipse. I always have to put my xpath between " " for working. Maybe, I am not being clear, sorry. Not sure, how to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
WebElement SeleccionCuentaDeOportunidad =findBy(String.format("(//*[contains(@title,'Jonathan')]//parent::span[1]/parent::th[1]//following-sibling::td[position()=1]//child::a[1])[@title=\"HER'S SISTEM S.A.\"]"))
```

Comment: How does this work with `findBy(String.format`?  Don't you need to tell it to find by xPath when you are using an xpath?

Comment: @C.Peck For Serenity we don't have to specify 'By.xpath'.

Comment: Aha.  Then your solution with the escapes looks good, I just wish I could see the actual page to create a more stable xpath or css selector.

Comment: @C.Peck Your are totally right , but I put finby(String.format because I will replace the name in that case "HER'S SISTEM S.A." to %s , that's mean I made a dinamic xpath , I only have to specify any name in my resources data.That's why I have the problem, because when I put a name that does not have this " ' " in my data , fine works well . On the other hand, when I use that name " HER'S SYSTEM" appears the problem for havin " ' " this in his name.